# python pandas convert date to milliseconds

Tags: pandas

I would like to know better way to convert date to milliseconds using only Pandas.

```
start_date = '2021-10-01 00:00:00'
start_date = pd.Timestamp(start_date)
print(start_date.timestamp()*1000)
```

return:

```
1633046400000.0
```

I would like to get the following variable without string operation:

```
1633046400000
```

How to convert '2021-10-01 00:00:00' smarter?

Comment: What is the difference? The first number is a float, the second number an integer. I would use the floating point number, since fractional milliseconds exist. There is no string operation involved here.

Comment: I would like to change this line: start_date.timestamp()*1000

Comment: So you want to change the formatting of the `print()` function from a float to an int?

Answer (score 0):

There is no millisecond output as string by default. As you have figured out, you might manipulate by numerical operations from float to string or you can use **strftime**;

```
start_date.strftime('%s%f')[:-3]
```

However *%f* formatting outputs microseconds (000000-999999) which you can truncate with a simple string manipulation to milliseconds.

> Output

```
1633046400000 <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap int around float variable convert int to float

```py
start_date = '2021-10-01 00:00:00'
start_date = pd.Timestamp(start_date)
print(int(start_date.timestamp()*1000))
```

Output:

> 1633046400000